# matlab corrcoef function returns NaN

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the `corrcoef` Kendall, Spearman and Pearson) with some arrays and it outputs `NaN`.

Can someone propose methods to know where and why it fails? Because the arrays are so large that I can not look to each element.

If not, where can I find the corrcoef whole code? I have searched but I do not find it.

Comment: You should post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. With the information you provide it's hard to tell what the problem is. To see `corrcoef` code, just type `edit corrcoef`. But __don't save__ any changes into the original function! Save with another name instead

Answer (score 1):

Most likely one of your inputs contains `NaN`. You can check whether there are any `NaN` elements using `isnan`, and find their indices using `find`:

```
>> A = randn(10,1);
>> A([3,8]) = NaN;
>> find(isnan(A))
ans =
     3
     8
```

As for looking up source code, you can highlight function name in your editor, then press `ctrl+D`. Note that some functions are built-in or mex, so you will not be able to read source code for them. But `corrcoef` is not one of them, so you can read the code.

Comment: Well, it seems that the array has no NaN. I put the code you said and it returns "Empty matrix: 0-by-1"

Comment: Then provide an example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: And how I do it? using fprintf to a .txt file? Just to know is useful

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the variance/ standard deviation equals zero in one of the arrays. Thus, in the correlation coefficient calculation when you divide by std or var (however it's implemented), you're actually dividing by zero which yield NaN.